# Onchange in select HTML, does not work (Django)

Tags: javascript, html, django, select, django-filter

I have a Problems model.

My Models `models.py`

```
class Problems(models.Model):

    Easy = 'Easy'
    Medium = 'Medium'
    Hard = 'Hard'
    NA = 'NA'
    DIFFICULTY = [
        (NA, 'NA'),
        (Easy, 'Easy'),
        (Medium, 'Medium'),
        (Hard, 'Hard'),
    ]
    ....
    name_problem = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=DIFFICULTY, default=NA)
    ....
```

I have connected a django-filter

My `filters.py`

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Easy = 'Easy'
    Medium = 'Medium'
    Hard = 'Hard'
    NA = 'NA'
    DIFFICULTY = [
        (NA, 'NA'),
        (Easy, 'Easy'),
        (Medium, 'Medium'),
        (Hard, 'Hard'),
    ]

    name_pr = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='name_problem', lookup_expr='icontains')
    diff = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(field_name='difficulty' ,choices=DIFFICULTY)

    class Meta:
        model = Problems
        fields = ['name_pr', 'diff']
```

My `views.py`

```
from .models import Problems
from .filters import ProductFilter

class MyProblemView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        problems = Problems.objects.all()
        filter = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=problems)
        problems = filter.qs
        context = {
            'problems': problems,
            'filter': filter,
        }
        return render(request, 'problems/problems.html', context)
```

And finally `html`

```
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <form action="/" name="form" method="get">
            {{ filter.form.diff }}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

    {% for problem in problems %}
        <p id="text"> {{ problem.name_problem }}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When there is a button in the form, it works

But I want it to be without a button to press. I am not any kind of proficient in JavaScript. So I wrote a simple function to use on `HTML SELECT`, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
            <form action="/" name="form" method="get">
                {% render_field filter.form.diff name='formsel' onchange='fav()' %}
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    
        {% for problem in problems %}
            <p id="text"> {{ problem.name_problem }}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
<script>
    function fav() {
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = form.formsel[form.formsel.selectedIndex].text
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think so it is a right way to use onchange

Comment: @HiteshMishra So what? Can u help?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure the ChoiceFilter in such way that it knows the JS function that `onchange` needs to trigger. In your code it could be something like

> ```
> diff = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(field_name='difficulty' ,choices=DIFFICULTY, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'fav();'}))
> ```

[you may use fav(this.value) if there to provide the chosen select value to the JS function but that is no needed here].
You don't need anything specific in the template.

Finally, the JavaScript does probably not need to change the selected index, I guess that it is already done.
What you need is to submit the form (this is what I understand when you write "When there is a button in the form, it works"). I am not sure that you even need to write a JS function for this as it only calls another function, but if you do, that would be something like

> function fav() {   document.getElementByName("form").submit(); }